# Discord.js restart command

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.io")
const { Message } = require("discord.js")
const ms = require("ms");

// set message listener 
exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
    if(!msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return msg.reply('You do not have permission to use this command.')
    msg.delete()
    setTimeout(() => {
    sendEm.delete()
    }, 10000);

// Turn bot off (destroy), then turn it back on
function resetBot(channel) {
    // send channel a message that you're resetting bot [optional]
    msg.channel.send('Restarting...')
    .then(msg => client.destroy())
    .then(() => client.login(config.token));
}}
```

I've had people do different like include this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    switch(message.content.toUpperCase()) {
        case '?RESTART':
            resetBot(message.channel);
            break;

        // ... other commands
    }
});
```

Is that code necessary or can I use what I have (first block)
Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly your issue is

Comment: I'm wondering what works and what doesnt xD!

Comment: I was wondering how to edit a message mainly

Comment: so you want to edit the message?

Comment: Yeah I want to edit the message saying

Comment: Restarting.....

Comment: `msg.edit('whatevergoeshere')`

Comment: So it changes to Restart Succesful!

Comment: Oook but how do you specify which message?

Comment: Because it says
"statement or declaration expected" for the .then(msg.edit('Restart worked'))

Comment: `.then(msg => msg.edit('Restart worked')`

Comment: oK lemme try that :)

Comment: @Dinty so this is my code:

`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JR4nzyDx

Comment: @Dinty it doesn't work

Comment: You need to close the expressions with brackets

Comment: I'll put it in as an answer

Comment: Ok then I'll wait

Comment: not working ;( 
1 error fixed other still not working

Comment: What error are you having? Also talk on my answer's comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing on from the discussion in comments, this is what you need to do:

```
const Discord = require("discord.io")
const { Message } = require("discord.js");
const { config } = require("dotenv/types");
const ms = require("ms");
 
// set message listener 
exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
    if(!msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
 msg.reply('You do not have permission to use this command.')
 
    msg.delete()
    setTimeout(() => {
    sendEm.delete()
    }, 10000);
} else {
 resetBot(msg.channel);
}
}
 
 
 
// Turn bot off (destroy), then turn it back on
async function resetBot(channel) {
    // send channel a message that you're resetting bot [optional]
    channel.send('Restarting...')
    .then(async msg => {
await client.destroy()
await client.login(config.token)
await msg.edit('Restart worked')
})}
```

If you have any issues let me know below.

Comment: Ok I will try now :)

Comment: Not working, same error

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: So click [here](https://ibb.co/GJNyBPM)

Comment: Oki, you changed it to await

Comment: Nope, didn't work, it still says declaration or statement expected, this time on the }) at the end

Comment: did you try actually running it?

Comment: Although [this](https://pastebin.com/zL9HSCLP) code worked, not sure if it is correct!

Comment: No, I didn't try to run, because in VSC, it doesn't let you if it has those "errors"

Comment: I use VSC, it does

Comment: Hmm ok, have you checked the code I posted ^^^

Comment: That looks like what i posted in my answer :P

Comment: What you've given me has 3 "errors"

Comment: I changed some } and )

Comment: I've updated my code a bit. If it resolved your issue don't forget to accept :)

Comment: Ok! Lemme see that

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```js
async function resetBot(channel) {
  const msg = await channel.send('Restarting...');

  await client.destroy();
  await client.login(config.token);
  await msg.edit('Restart worked');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Someone has already said that sorry ;(

Comment: LOL it was the same